How to write a GPU worker pool to run multiple tasks at the same time in bash?
Suppose there are 4 CUDA devices (0,1,2,3) on my computer and there are 10 tasks to run, each tasks is a script named run01.sh, run02.sh, ..., run10.sh.
The problem is, each task use only 1 GPU, I want to write a bash script to run those 10 tasks at the same time to make best use of the 4 CUDA devices. How can I make it?
Update:
To address @RenaudPacalet's question

Please edit your question and explain how you specify which device to use for a given job.

There are 4 workers (4 CUDA devices), what I want is to find out a solution in bash which ensure:

1 worker can only handle 1 task at a time.
there should be no free workers if there are remaining tasks.


Your question is not really a programming question and it somehow asks for recommendations, which is out of scope here. Did you look at GNU parallel?

@RenaudPacalet I don't think parallel or xargs can deal with this as there are only 4 CUDA devices. for 10 tasks. And parallel/xargs cannot allocate limited resources to mutliple tasks. I would like to know is there any useful bash technique can be used to solve this issue.

there are only 4 CUDA devices. for 10 tasks That's what parallel or xargs are made for: launch a given number of jobs (4 in your case), no more, keep this workload by starting a new job each time a job completes, until all jobs complete (10 in your case). See the -P option.

GPU are massively parallel devices, and they can execute tasks of multiple process without any problem as long as you have enough memory for all the tasks (note that each task is already parallel but may not always saturate the GPU). In fact, besides memory, the overall execution can often be faster with more task running in parallel because GPU can overlap latency stall with other tasks. And yes, xargs can be used for that. You can also use a basic bash script and count concurrent jobs with jobs -r | wc -l in a loop running the tasks.

@RenaudPacalet I am aware of the -P option, but the problem is how can I specified different devices to different tasks with parallel?

@link89 Please edit your question and explain how you specify which device to use for a given job.

To make a job use specific CUDA GPUs you can set the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES.
Now, if you need to limit the number of jobs that can run at the same time on a single GPU then a possible solution is to use a fifo queue with the list of available GPUs; the idea is that each job will have to "take" a GPU from the fifo queue, and after said job completes, it writes the GPU it's been using to the fifo so that a new job can use it.
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo free_gpus
exec 3<>free_gpus

# write the GPUs you want to use (0,1,2,3) into the fifo.
# for 2 jobs per GPU, write each GPU twice.
printf '%s\n' 0 1 2 3 >&3 &

for exe in run*.sh
do
    read gpu # allocate a GPU (blocks until there's one available)
    { CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="$gpu" "$exe"; echo "$gpu" >&3; } &
done <&3
wait


Cool solution. I don't get it until I read explanation of chatgpt.

chatGPT beaks it down nicely indeed
